# Fancybox3 fix js library

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't get this basic code to work for fancybox3. Is it not loading the js library?

Original site is here: http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/

```
<!doctype html>
<html><head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.0.47/jquery.fancybox.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.0.47/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<a data-fancybox="gallery" href="big_1.jpg">
<img src="small_1.jpg">
</a>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The example in the docs explicitly embeds the fancybox script _after_ the HTML elements it is supposed to work on. If you embed it before, then you might need to use JS method of initialization instead.

Answer (score 0):

Put the scripts before the closing `body` tag.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.0.47/jquery.fancybox.min.css" />
</head>

<body>

  <a data-fancybox="gallery" href="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/yaqe1qesQ8c/maxresdefault.jpg">
    <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/yaqe1qesQ8c/maxresdefault.jpg">
  </a>
  
  
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.0.47/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Still couldn't get this version to work correctly. Does this work for you?  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Weird. Do you know why this would work in chrome and firefox, but when I run it in safari it gives me this error: {
  "message": "Script error.",
  "filename": "",
  "lineno": 0,
  "colno": 0
}

Answer (score 0):

worked great by adding:

```
<link rel="stylesheet prefetch" href="jquery.fancybox.min.css">
```

With adding script above body close tag as recommend by others

Thanks guys.